# Design SharePoint pages using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, design

I'm working on SharePoint Online using Office 365.

I was using Visual Studio 2015 to create a app (add-in) and show it in my SharePoint site.

Now, I need to make the SharePoint site to more unique, like the http://www.border.gov.au/ site.

Can any one please suggest a method to do it or please share the reference site?

The sites and methods I have followed are listed below,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx  - for creating and adding the apps(add-in's).

Comment: Are you serving the App in the App Domain or is it rendered in the Host Domain?

Comment: its rendered in Host Domain